# How can I allocate memory for triple pointer using a function?

Tags: c++

I would like to allocate memory to store/manipulate data using a triple pointer. Given that I have to allocate the data at multiple points in my code, I implemented a function to do it. In the code below I give the implementation of this function and a simple main method that illustrates how I use this function in my code.

The code compile without error but when I run the program it crushes.  I would appreciate your help to fix this problem.

EDIT: it crushes in the function AllocateMemory at the line 
    *data[i][j] = new double[x]; 
for i = 0 and j =1

Thank you.

```
int main()
{
    int x = 2;
    int y = 2;
    int z = 2;
    double*** data;//
    AllocateMemory(&data, x, y, z);
    //play with data

    FreeMemory(data, x, y, z);
    return 0;
}



void AllocateMemory(double**** data, int x, int y, int z)
{
    *data = new double**[z];

    for(int i = 0; i < z; i++)
    {
        *data[i] = new double*[y];
        for(int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            *data[i][j] = new double[x];
        }

    }
}


void FreeMemory(double*** data, int x, int y, int z)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < z; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            delete [] data[i][j];
            data[i][j] = NULL;
        }
        delete [] data[i];
        data[i] = NULL;
    }

    delete [] data;
    data = NULL;
}
```

Comment: where does it crashes?

Comment: You'll need to figure out the line on which the program crashses.

Comment: Oh, a [three star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)!  Wait, that's 4!

Comment: it crushes at the line  *data[i][j] = new double[x]; in the function AllocateMemory 
 for I =0 and j =1

Comment: @user3026374 put the relevant information into the question.

Comment: As you tag c++, you may use `double***& data` (which would avoid your operator precedence issue). Better would be to use `std::vector`.

Comment: Note also that your `data = NULL;` is useless (modify only local `data`, not the one in main).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that array subscription has a higher precedence than dereference operator. Here:

```
*data[i] = new double*[y];
```

You're subscripting `data` and then dereferencing that pointer. `data` argument of `AllocateMemory` is not a pointer to an array, but instead to a single variable which is `data` in `main`. Therefore `data[1]` was never initialized and you get undefined behaviour. Given the context, you probably intended it the other way round:

```
(*data)[i] = new double*[y];
```

You have the same bug on the line `*data[i][j] = new double[x];`.

You could have avoided this either by using a reference parameter or - as I would recommend - by returning the pointer to the newly allocated array of pointers instead of passing it as an argument.